# Why do the colours of my model blur together?

Tags: opengl

I have been trying to get an object to be lit properly all day long, without results, so I'm going to try here. In the essence, I am trying the object to look like this:

[image: A part of my 3D model in GLC player (a 3D model viewer)]

While in my program it looks like this:

[image: A part of a 3D model drawn by my renderer]

Here's my context:

```
glClearDepth(1.0);
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
glLight(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, {0, 5, 0, 1});
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

And my material/lighting settings:

```
glMaterialf(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, 10);

glLight(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, {0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0});
glLight(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, {0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0});
glLight(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, {0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 1.0});

glMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, {1, 0.8078, 0});
glMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, {1, 0.8078, 0});
glMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, {0.5, 0.5, 0.5});
glMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_EMISSION, {0, 0, 0});
```

[I used {r, g, b, a} to denote an array for simplicity. I looked up the actual values that were used to draw the model and wrote them into the arrays]

The main problem is that whenever my objects get fully lit, everything "clutters" together into the ambient colour. There are no lighter and darker parts depending on the orientation of the fragment anymore, just one chunk of solid colour.

I have searched the whole project for openGL settings I may have missed, though the only thing I found was what you see above (omitting a few calls to reset the projection and modelview matrices, clearing the screen, and a translation/rotation).

I have also tried to alter the values of the lights and materials, without much success. Changing the ambient colour just causes the whole model to become brighter. I also tried moving the light.

EDIT: By request, here's how I store and draw the model:

I load the model from an OBJ file. I looked at the file itself, which lists normals. The loader also recognizes that.

Here's how it draws the VBO:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vertexBufferID);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, stride, 0 * 4);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, stride, 3 * 4);
glBindBufferARB(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, indexBufferID);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, this.numberOfVertices, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

The VBO is interleaved, formatted like [vertex, normal, vertex, normal, ..]. I dropped some print calls in the drawing code, and it sets the vertex and normal pointers. Hence I am pretty sure that the VBO itself is loaded and drawn correctly.

Comment: Have you set any normals for your mesh?

Comment: @Bart: Yes, they were in the 3D model file I loaded it from (the model is stored in a VBO).

Comment: Then please show us how you set up and render the mesh. From what I can tell it looks as if you have no normals set at all.

Comment: @Bart: sure. Give me a minute.

Comment: @Bart: Here is my drawing code. I do get more of that 'interesting' style lighting when I look at the model from more of a distance, but it is at the boundary where the light gets too bright (= the ambient colour), and too dark (almost black).

Comment: @Bart: Ok, I seem to have found something.. Apparently in addition to setting vertex and normal pointers it also set texture coordinate pointers (due to that I forgot break; lines in a switch). When I only set the vertex and normal pointers, the java binary instantly crashes.

Comment: It's probably crashing because you leave texture_coord_array client state enabled, so it tries to access whatever is at the texcoord pointer, which is null. Did you remove the enable for texture client state?

Comment: @Tim and Bart: You guys made my day. Looks fantastic! Too bad I can't accept comments as an answer :(

Comment: @Tim Just make that an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's crashing because you leave texture_coord_array client state enabled, so it tries to access whatever is at the texcoord pointer, which is null.

Answer (score 1):

So with many problems, the answer is often unexpected. The first part was the switch statement I used to determine how to set the data pointers of the VBO:

```
private void setDataPointers() {
    int stride = this.dataFormat.elementsPerVertex * 4;
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, stride, 0 * 4);
    switch(this.dataFormat)
    {
        case VERTICES_AND_TEXTURES:
            glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, stride, (3)*4);
        case VERTICES_AND_NORMALS:
            glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, stride, 3 * 4);
        case VERTICES_TEXTURES_NORMALS:
            glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, stride, 3 * 4);
            glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, stride, (3 + 3) * 4); 
    }
}
```

As you can see the break; statements are missing. So the vertex, normal AND texture pointers would be set.

Second, when drawing the VBO, all three client side modes were enabled:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
```

So the renderer was looking for texture coordinates that didn't exist, and somehow spit out the strange unlit geometry.

Comment: Your compiler should have a warning you can enable for switch case fallthrough (and some way to explicitly ask for fallthrough so you don't hit the warning when you want it, [such as](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#clang__fallthrough))